# How to fix "RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver: Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1050019"?

Tags: android, notifications

When testing an app on old Android OS builds using the emulator, on API v12 it crashes with a `Resources$NotFoundException`. What causes this? How to avoid it?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.onefishtwo.bbqtimer.AlarmReceiver: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1050019
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1908)
        ...
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1050019
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDimensionPixelSize(Resources.java:600)
        at android.app.Notification$Builder.makeRemoteViews(Notification.java:938)
        at android.app.Notification$Builder.makeContentView(Notification.java:954)
        at android.app.Notification$Builder.getNotification(Notification.java:984)
        at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatHoneycomb.add(NotificationCompatHoneycomb.java:52)
        at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplHoneycomb.build(NotificationCompat.java:115)
        at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder.build(NotificationCompat.java:612)
        at com.onefishtwo.bbqtimer.Notifier.openOrCancel(Notifier.java:156)
        at com.onefishtwo.bbqtimer.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1901)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1052)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's a simplified version of the code in `openOrCancel()`:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setNumber(numReminders);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build()); // ***THROWS***
```

- It works fine on Android OS API v15 and later. The purpose of `NotificationCompat.Builder` is to handle backward compatibility.
- Resource ID #0x1050019 is not an app resource.
- A clean build doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a while debugging this. `NotificationCompat` isn't doing its job here.

**Workaround:** Don't call `builder.setNumber()` on OS builds older than API v15:

```
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentText(contentText);

// WORKAROUND a Resources$NotFoundException bug.
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15) {
    builder.setNumber(numReminders);
}
```

In theory, you could call `builder.setContentInfo()` instead, but that has no visible impact on API v12.

[I can't tell if the bug also happens on API v13 (HONEYCOMB_MR2) because the v13 emulator takes most of an hour to launch, then croaks. Every time.]